# "a song in which to weep"

Tags: meaning

*This is a weeping song /  A song in which to weep.*

I would like to ask how I should understand the passage in italics. Is it possible to paraphrase it as "a song which forces us to weep". Is this a standard structure or is this – for me a little bit odd – condensation of the adjective subordinate clause  used because this is the lyric.

Comment: The lyric could be compared to "This is a time in which to exercise restraint" where the implied subject is "one" and the infinitive is a form of mild imperative: One should exercise restraint at this time. So, a song where one should cry. Who that "one" is is not clear. The speaker in the time for restraint example, or the singer in the song example, or those listening to the speaker or to the singer, i.e. "everyone".  "we should"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [Nick Cave & The Bad Seeds - The Weeping Song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TqhOVY58zIo), the lyrics describe an unspecified sad situation (not stated in the song) in which women and their men are weeping and children are crying and yet to weep.

He makes the distinction between "crying" and "weeping"

> Father, why are all the children weeping?
>   They are merely crying son
>   O, are they merely crying, father?
>   Yes, true weeping is yet to come

The song is meant to recognize the sadness, not necessarily to make the listener cry or weep.  Similar to telling a sad tale.

> This is a weeping song
>   A song in which to weep

One telling part is the "weeping" seems to happen at night when people are sleeping

> While all the men and women sleep
>
> While all the little children sleep

and the "I won't be weeping long" has a foreboding that *something* will happen by daybreak.

> This is a weeping song
>   But I won't be weeping long

It is a song about weeping, and the melody reflects that.

> This is a weeping song

is merely stating what kind of song it is

> A song in which to weep

is stylized in its description and could be paraphrased as "a song for weeping".